Horizontal lines on left side of rendered video
I've just rendered a 1080 x 1920 video and noticed that there are these tiny horizontal lines that are persisting through the entire length of the video on the left side. Seen below marked by the black arrows.
I've double checked the image frames that the render is being produced from, and those lines are not there. I've also tried different codecs and players, and the same issue persists.
Any work arounds for this?

